# jQuery Validate, accept $ sign

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a custom validator, which accept numbers including comma or dot, and that's perfect. But now, I want this same validator to accept the $ sign too. Examples :

> 122,00 $
>   122.05 $
>   122$
>   122.10$

All of these entries should be accepted.

Actually, my validator is :

```
$.validator.addMethod("money", function (value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?)$/);
}, "Please provide a valid dollar amount");
```

What should I do to make I also accept the dollar sign ?

Thanks

Comment: I've never seen an input field where you have to type your currency yourself... The currency sign is usually displayed outside, and just a number is expected from the customer

Comment: I know, try te explain that to my customer :(

Comment: Also if the user adds it themselves, wouldn't they put it at the front: $122?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add \$? to the beginning of the regex and \s?\$? to the end of the regex. Doing so will accept: $1,234, 1,234$, and 1,234 $:

```
$.validator.addMethod("money", function (value, element) {
   return this.optional(element) || value.match(/^\$?(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d{2})?)\s?\$?$/);
}, "Please provide a valid dollar amount");
```